# Can "childs" ever be the plural of "child", in standard English?

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, non-standard

Is the word *childs* ever used instead of *children* for the plural of *child*? And was it ever a part of standard English vocabulary but later neglected?

Comment: only for software developers :)

Answer (score 16):

No, "childs" was never a plural of child. See Etymononline's entry for [*child*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=child):

> The difficulty with the plural began in Old English, where the
>   nominative plural was at first *cild*, identical with the singular, then
>   c.975 a plural form *cildru* (genitive *cildra*) arose, probably for
>   clarity's sake, only to be re-pluraled late 12c. as *children*, which is
>   thus a double plural. Middle English plural *cildre* survives in
>   Lancashire dialect *childer* and in *[Childermas](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=Childermas&allowed_in_frame=0)*.

The German equivalent of *children* is *Kinder*, the Dutch *kinderen*. The plural form with *r* in children seems very stable. So it is improbable that children will ever be replaced with *childs*.

Comment: Hi, rogermue, I edited your post with a link and its essential part. Please take a look.

Answer (score 9):

The word in Old English is the neuter noun *cild*, which wasn't inflected for nominative and accusative, either singular or plural.  (You can check out the [Old English Translator](http://www.oldenglishtranslator.co.uk/) if you wish.) In late Old English, the word took on the inflections of another class of neuter nouns, those with *-u/-o* stems, which had nominative plurals *-ru*.  This per the *OED*.  (You can also go [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Old_English/Nouns).)  Thus the plural (in the nominative) became *cildru*.  This change was adopted in the southern dialects, but the north was more conservative, with Northumbrian keeping *cild* and making its plural *cildas*, from an attraction to that plural of *-a* stem masculine nouns.  Further north in Scotland, there is the Scottish *chield*, which always had the plural *chields*.

Middle English moved the *-ru* ending to *-re*, which eventually became the standard for dialects, north and south.  The north retained the plural *childre*, but the south adopted *children* as the plural along the lines of other nouns ending in -re like *brethre* (brother) with its plural *brethren*.

The *OED* tells us that *childes* survived until the 15th century from the Northumbrian *cildas*, but that *children* became the "standard and literary" winner.

Answer (score 0):

Child:

Old English cild, of Germanic origin. The Middle English plural childer or childre became childeren or children by association with plurals ending in -en, such as brethren.

Oxford English Dictionary

Therefore, no.