# Can the word 'child' be pluralised : 'childs two, three and four'?

Tags: irregular-plurals

The question ["Can 'childs' ever be the plural of 'child' in standard English ?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/308706/can-childs-ever-be-the-plural-of-child-in-standard-english) produced answers which agreed that it could not.

However, I notice today that, in Court, children, who had been named for the sake of anonymity as 'child two', 'child three' and 'child four', had been collectively referred to as 'childs two, three and four'.

> Earlier in the inquest, the court heard Shukri had gone down to the river after school with Child One and three others ­— known as Childs Two, Three and Four.

[Bolton News 26th February 2020](https://www.theboltonnews.co.uk/news/18263498.schoolgirl-was-laughing-bury-12-year-old-drowned-inquest-told/)

This appears to me to be perfectly correct.

Are the Court, the newspaper report and myself all wrong in thinking that this is a 'standard English' way of properly referring to the children in question ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can "childs" ever be the plural of "child", in standard English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/308706/can-childs-ever-be-the-plural-of-child-in-standard-english) The OED stance is given here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I noticed that question before writing my own. The conclusion is at odds with what has appeared in Court and in print. Hence my own question.This application was not considered in the previous question or answers.

Comment: OED carries out corpus studies to examine what should be considered standard practice (and emulated). The odd counterexamples one encounters do not establish an acceptable alternative. And courts have been guilty of missentencing in the past. // [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/childs) is cogent here: **childs** (nonstandard, rare) plural of child ...
_Usage notes_
Primarily used in dialogue, to indicate that a foreign or illiterate speaker has a poor grasp of the English language.

Comment: And I'm not convinced that the court actually used the term 'childs'; this could be the reporter wrongly abbreviating 'Child Two, Child Three, and Child Four'. _Try contacting the editor._

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I suppose it may hang on what part of speech 'child' is in the title 'child one'. 'Children one, two and three' _in this context_ does not seem to me (as a native speaker) as 'correct' as 'childs one, two and three' but I am not certain I can actually explain why I say that.

Comment: No, it hangs on what the vast majority of people consider standard. And do. // A single counterexample is a totally insufficient reason to post a duplicate challenging a reasonable answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes. I take your point, sir. But it is still an interesting example and I think it deserves consideration on its own merit.

Comment: Child is pluralized only in reference to  (child) One, Two, Three and Four.  Nothing  to do with children.

Comment: @user067531 I'm sorry. That is not a convincing argument. What part of speech are you saying (child) is ?

Comment: If you had paper instead of child:  paper One,  paper Two and paper Three. You’d say  papers 1, 2 and 3. Child, in above juridical sense, is a unit.

Comment: If there was any specialist usage of a regularised plural _childs_ that was common enough to be relevant to Anglophones in general, dictionaries would have picked up on it. This was covered at the **duplicate**.

Comment: I'm leaning toward the expression 'child two, three and four', the word 'child' being a heading to bracket the list of numbers.

Answer (score -1):

The plural of child is children.

Collectively, "child one, child two and child three" refer to the children involved.

Perhaps the Editor of the newspaper in question was on holiday when the paper was "put to bed"?

Comment: Please examine claimed potential duplicates before submitting an 'answer'. And note that even correct answers, if unsupported by linked and attributed references, come across as (and may be no more than) personal opinion. Imagine someone answering "Can the plural of 'mouse' ever be 'mouses'?" with "The plural of 'mouse' is 'mice'."

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - I appreciate the comments you have made to me and in response to the question asked by Nigel J.  I shall, in future, apply your advice.